In gnu make how subst works?
Please explain to me what this line of make does(the subst part)?
TRACK_CFLAGS = $(CC):$(subst ','\'',$(ALL_CFLAGS)):$(USE_GETTEXT_SCHEME)

I think it should replace single quote character with \'.

Questions here should show that you've tried to find the solution yourself. The documentation page 8.2 Functions for String Substitution and Analysis is quite clear and concise on how subst is used.

I think it should replace single quote character should be replaced with '.
If it's right but it doesn't work, this is why I'm asking here.

It replaces a single quote with '', just as it appears to.  Make doesn't pay attention to quotes at all (except on one odd context).  In almost all places, a quote (single or double) is just a regular character like a or b as far as make is concerned.


I think it should replace single quote character with \'.

This will explain:
$ cat Makefile
in := 'aa'bb'
out_wrong := $(subst ','\'',$(in))
out_right := $(subst ',\',$(in))
$(info in=[$(in)])
$(info $$(subst ','\'',$$(in)) = [$(out_wrong)] (wrong))
$(info $$(subst ',\',$$(in)) = [$(out_right)] (right))

all:

$ make
in=['aa'bb']
$(subst ','\'',$(in)) = ['\''aa'\''bb'\''] (wrong)
$(subst ',\',$(in)) = [\'aa\'bb\'] (right)
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.


Are you sure that that's the full context?  As you and Mike point out, this subst function is wrong as it's used here.  But, this is not normally how it is used; normally the variable is itself quoted with a single quote.
For example it would normally be something like this:
sometarget:
        do something '$(subst ','\',$(ARGS))'

By adding the single quotes around the outside of the variable, then having the extra inner single quote makes sense.
In the above example if we had:
ARGS = some'quoted'content

then the subst would result in:
do something 'some'\''quoted'\''content'

which is correct and does what you want.
ETA
Yes, I was right.  Here's the full context omitted from the original question, including where the variable is used:
TRACK_CFLAGS = $(CC):$(subst ','\'',$(ALL_CFLAGS)):$(USE_GETTEXT_SCHEME)

GIT-CFLAGS: FORCE
        @FLAGS='$(TRACK_CFLAGS)'; \
  ...

You can see that when the variable TRACK_CFLAGS is expanded, it's inside an outer '.  That means that the subst function is correct as it is and should not be changed.
I personally find it a bit odd to separate the external quoting from the subst function; if it were me I would do it all in one place, in the recipe itself, as it seems less confusing.  But the behavior in the makefile is not wrong.

This is the original source code
https://github.com/git/git/blob/b31fb630c0fc6869a33ed717163e8a1210460d94/Makefile#L3145
